# Discord.js joining voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need my bot joins a voice channel on ready here is my code

```
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
client.on('ready', () => {
        joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: client.channels.cache.get('862785346767814696')
        })
})
```

it return with error  (o is not a function)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a guild ID and voice adapter creator

```js
joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: "channelId",
  guildId: "guildId",
  adapterCreator: client.guilds.cache.get("guildId").voiceAdapterCreator
})
```

Comment: getting this error

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voiceAdapterCreator')